# Summary XMLFile Does Not Conform to Schema

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, generic-test

I have a series of generic tests that run automatically from a TFS build definition. Some tests that pass are reported as failed in Visual Studio with the message "Summary XMLFile Does Not Conform to Schema". The XML files of the tests with that message are the same as tests that have no problems. Is there anything else that could cause this message? Would something like non-printable characters in the XML file cause it to fail schema validation?

(duplicate of [my MSDN forums post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce9efdcb-e3fb-4395-ac17-972add3a0db8/summary-xmlfile-does-not-conform-to-schema))

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by duplicate (non-unique) `<TestName>` values that I overlooked.